# Why this doesn't change my dataframe row?

Tags: python, pandas

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    add_tid(row, label)

df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf8')

def add_tid(row, label):
    ...
    row['tid'] = get_tid(label)
```

For each row, I have the add_tid() function to change the row. But the test.csv doesn't have the updated 'tid' info.

How to update each  row while iterating it?

Comment: return the value from get_tid(label) and update 'tid' within for loop.  looping is an anti-pattern. objective is not clear from what you have in question, otherwise someone can suggest a vectorized approach

Comment: the `df.iterrows` loop over your dataframe so you re not updating the data instead you re updating  a generated object by the loop to update the data you can overwrite the column by using `apply` function or use the `.loc` methode to loop over your dataframe

Comment: Given certain condition, I want to update the 'tid' column for each row. @Naveed

Comment: @to_data, if I add 'df.iloc[index] = row' in the for loop, it's extremely slow. Do you mean '.iloc'?

Comment: You need to use `df.loc[index,target_column] = get_tid(label)`.

Comment: @marlon the `iloc` could work to